# Ограничение на количество запросов к google поиску

Tags: google-search

Существует ли такое ограничение? Если да, то буду признателен ссылкам на доки, сам не смог найти хоть какое-то упоминание об этом.

Comment: Эти данные не афишируются поисковиком.

Comment: @AK, [**разве**](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing)? (В качестве Custom Search можно использовать обычный Google поиск). Спасибо.

Comment: @Dmitry, см. [**сюда**](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing). Если ограничения для Вашего проекта малы, а платить не хочется, рекомендую почитать [**это руководство**](https://benbernardblog.com/web-scraping-and-crawling-are-perfectly-legal-right/). // На практике в моём небольшом приложении осуществляется 1 запрос в 5 секунд — пока не банили. См. также [**примечания**](https://github.com/aviaryan/python-gsearch#warning) реального проекта, использующего скрапинг Google SERP. Спасибо.

Comment: @Dmitry, думаю, Вы это имели в виду, — Вы пишете проект, в котором отправляются запросы к Google поиску, — когда спрашивали. Если нет, пожалуйста, уточните Ваш вопрос. Спасибо.